# Optimizing getting one match from list

Tags: java

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class Person { 
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
   }
   // getters and setters
}
```

Let's say I have a list of `Person` objects, and I want to find one Person object in the list whose first name is **'John'**.

The shortest code I can think of doing this job is:

```
personList.stream()
    .filter(person -> person.getFirstName().equals("John"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .get(0);
```

As you can see, it's not that short. Can you think of a shorter way?

---

**Edit**: 
Some people recommended to use `findFirst()`. In this case, the code will be:

```
personList.stream()
    .filter(person -> person.getFirstName().equals("John"))
    .findFirst()
    .get()
```

It's only a little bit shorter.

Comment: Or `findFirst()`

Comment: `Stream.findFirst()` ([here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)'s a link to the Stream API, you might want to read it)

Comment: @Zabuza `anyMatch` returns boolean value, not object

Comment: True that, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I probably meant `findAny()`.

Comment: Are you really asking for **short** code? Or efficient, or readable? Or a good compromise between all factors, i.e. the *recommended* way?

Comment: This is also short: `for(Person p:personList)if(p.getFirstName().equals("John"))return p;return null;`. But is there any particular reason why you want to write the shortest code? If it is just for fun, [you might get more fun here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The shortest code will be `personList.find("John")`, but the reasoning behind it is more suitable for codereview section. If you are interested, contact me in a chat, I can share my thoughts about it.

Answer (score 2):

### Stream#findAny

You can use `Stream#findAny` for this. It returns an `Optional<Person>`, empty in case there is no hit.

```
Optional<Person> person = personStream.filter(p -> p.getFirstName().equals("John")).findAny();
```

From its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny()):

> Returns an `Optional` describing some element of the stream, or an **empty** `Optional` if the stream is empty.

There is also `findFirst`, but `findAny` is two characters less and potentially has a faster implementation.

---

### Method reference

The code gets shorter if you move the filter into a dedicated method:

```
public static boolean isJohn(Person p) {
    return "John".equals(p.getFirstName());
}
```

Then the code gets

```
Optional<Person> person = personStream.filter(MyClass::isJohn).findAny();
```

---

### Predicate

If you move the filter into a dedicated predicate, it even gets shorter:

```
Predicate<Person> isJohn = p -> "John".equals(p.getFirstName());
```

Then we get

```
Optional<Person> person = personStream.filter(isJohn).findAny();
```

---

### As short as possible

Sacrificing readability for the sake of short code (**never do this**), we may replace the variable names and get:

```
Optional<Person> p = s.filter(j).findAny();
```

---

### Notes

Prefer to compare `"John"` against the name of the person, not the other way around. This way, it is `null`-safe. You could also use `Objects#equals` to get `null`-safety. I.e.

```
// Not null-safe
p.getFirstName().equals("John");

// Null safe
"John".equals(p.getFirstName());
Objects.equals("John", p.getFirstName());
```

Do not call `get()` on `Optional` without proving that the call will not crash. Not following this so defeats the purpose of `Optional`. Instead, prefer the `orElseXXX` methods. Or at least guard the access with an `if (result.isEmpty())`.

Comment: Plus one for *never sacrifice readability for the sake of short code*.

Comment: It's not like your dedicated methods aren't part of the code needed to achieve this, anymore. But I respect the effort to really find a short solution ;) Or at least a short call to this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

### Standard library

With just the standard library, use what the other answers provide. It's relatively short, clear, standard, everybody will understand it. It forces you to explicitly handle the case of the element not being present, and that's a good thing. The only "unnecessary" boilerplate is the `stream()` call, and that has its subtle semantic rationale, too.

```java
Person john = personList.stream()
    .filter(person -> person.getFirstName().equals("John"))
    .findFirst()
    .get();
```

### 3rd party libraries

If you can use a library, there are shorter (though not necessarily better) solutions. Using [Google Guava's](https://github.com/google/guava) [`Iterables.find()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#find-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Predicate-):

```java
Person john = Iterables.find(personList, person -> person.getFirstName().equals("John"));
```

(Note that this throws an exception if the element is not found. Consider using the other `find()` method with a default value, or the `tryFind()` method.)

The same is available in many other libraries, e.g. [Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/): [`IterableUtils.find()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.3/org/apache/commons/collections4/IterableUtils.html#find-java.lang.Iterable-org.apache.commons.collections4.Predicate-).

The above mentioned Guava also has the [`onlyElement()`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MoreCollectors.html#onlyElement--) collector:

```java
Person john = personList.stream()
    .filter(person -> person.getFirstName().equals("John"))
    .collect(MoreCollectors.onlyElement());
```

### A different approach

Searching a list for a specific element is a linear, or O(n), operation. If you'll be doing this repeatedly, it's clear that you should be using a different data structure. Perhaps a map from person name to persons would be more useful?

```java
Map<String, Person> personsByFirstName = personList.stream()
    .collect(toMap(Person::getFirstName, Function.identity()));
Person john = personsByFirstName.get("John");
```

(Note this only preserves a single person per first name. Probably not what you want, is it?)

Answer (score 1):

Shorter is not necessarily better. Use code that's either more efficient or more readable/maintainable.

This is shorter, but worse in many ways:

```
personList.removeIf(p -> !"John".equals(p.getFirstName()));
```

`Stream.findFirst` improves the efficiency, by stopping the stream as soon as the first element is found:

```
personList.stream()
          .filter(person -> person.getFirstName.equals("John"))
          .findFirst() //<-- This will stop your stream when the first match is found
          .get();
```

But when you need to avoid calling `get` on an empty `Optional`, you'll have to make it longer.

These are just 2 examples showing that you can degrade the code's quality by trying to make it short at all cost.

It's a trade-off, up to the developer (as everything is). In my opinion, the choice between efficiency/readability and brevity of code is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Stream.findFirst(), but don't think in the way whats the most shortest. Instead always create the code, that is the easiest to understand (in this case it would be findFirst). And i don't think that 2 or 3 characters in code matter.

```
    List<Person> test = new ArrayList<>();

    test.stream().filter(s -> s.getFirstName().equals("John")).findFirst();
```

Comment: OPs stream is a stream of `Person`s, not `String`s.

Answer (score 0):

I personally suggest taking a look at the apache commons libraries, which supply a lot of helpful utilities. http://commons.apache.org/
The Collections-package (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) has a `IterableUtils`-utility class, which allows you to do the following:

```
Person john = IterableUtils.find(personList, person -> person.getFirstName().equals("John"));
```

Aside from this, it offers a bunch of other helpful stuff. Or more to your example:

```
Predicate<Person> isJohn = p -> "John".equals(p.getFirstName());
Person john = IterableUtils.find(personList, isJohn);
```